# How to split a file alternating the prefix used for the output files?

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

I have large file. It is made of parts of 40 lines each. There are two types of parts and they alternate. The two types of parts should be numbered independently. So the first part should be `X_0001`, the second part should be `Y_0001`, then `X_0002`, `Y_0002`, etc.

I used this command but it can only split into pieces with the same prefix:

```
 split -d -l 40 -a 4  inputfile X_
```

Comment: So each chunk of 80 lines has to be sorted and then the first 40 lines go to `X_???` and the last 40 lines go to `Y_???`, right ?

Comment: exactly this what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `split` and rename the files afterwards.

But the simplest is probably to call awk. You can use the `>` redirection operator to write to a file instead of standard output. The variable `NR` contains the current line number.

Awk's redirection automatically takes care of opening files. You should close files explicitly if you use a lot of different ones, otherwise you might run into a limit on open files.

```
awk '
  (NR-1) % 40 == 0 { close(out); out = sprintf("%s_%04d", (NR % 80 == 1 ? "X" : "Y"), NR/80+1); }
  { print >out }
' inputfile
```

Comment: this split the file only to two parts, but the file has 4000 lines so the results should be   50 files of X_{00..50} and  50 files of Y_{00..50}

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy Oh, I see. Your question was worded strangely but I hadn't understood that. I've updated my answer to match this.

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu split` you could use the `--filter` option:

```
split --numeric-suffixes=0001 -l 80 -a 4 \
--filter='sed -n -e "1,40w $FILE" -e "41,80w ${FILE/X/Y}"' infile X_
```

This will split the file into 80-lines pieces, piping the content of each piece to `sed` which writes the first 40 lines to `$FILE` (the piece name, in this case `split` replaces it with `X_????` - see `man split`) and the rest to `${FILE/X/Y}` which is the same name but with `X` replaced by `Y`.

---

Since the requirement has changed and you only need to split into pieces with alternating names you could also use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1;p="X"}
{close(fn);fn=sprintf("%s_%04d", p, c);print >> fn} 
NR%40==0{p="Y"}NR%80==0{p="X";c++}' file1
```

This sets the piece name based on two variables, `p`refix and `c`ounter. Each 40 lines, the `p`refix changes to `Y`, each 80 lines the `p`refix changes to `X` and the `c`ounter is incremented.

Comment: it works when I replaced  _--numeric-suffixes=000_'  by  _ -d_;   but this sort the lines before splitting and this is unwanted

Comment: sorry; maybe I didn't read your comment well